# Tcp message parser call in a thread, merge many tcp message in one response

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp

Currently I am working on project in which I have a TCP communication with a device, but a have a problem and I need your advice.

I am using a TCP client (MINA). For it I wrote a custom protocol so I can code and decode the message that are byte[]. And that is all OK. 
Now when I receive a message from the device I call message_parser(message) in the thread, that should give me event for what message is received.
Now I saw that in the message the device sends there is  a flag_for_more_message that means that additional messages will follow
In the moment when I receive a message I process it and I throw out an event. But there is a problem when I need to get several messages in a row for one message(event).
 In one thread I will receive just one part of the message, then the other part etc and I need to merge them somehow, and to through out response class in which I have the response.

So which is a better idea:
1) the threads to write in a general variables and to follow the flag_for_more_message and to merge the messages, or
2) to write in a database and the merge them from there

if you have any better idea please say so.

Looking forward your response.

Comment: I would merge the messages in a ByteArrayOutputStream unless you need something more complex.

Comment: I take the bytearray and make a hexstring and i operate with the string but know i have 2 tcp message in separate threads (2 x hex strings) that is one message and i need a way to parse them as one message and to fire a event

Comment: I would take the multiple byte[] and write them to a ByteArrayOutputStream to make one bigger byte[].  No Strings are required, it will just use more memory and be slower.

Comment: example:
mess1 is : 0x40 0x50 0x55 etc
i call the parser (in a thread)
i get mess 2: 0x34 0x35 0x20 etc
i call the parser (in a thread)
i need one result from 2 message

but i have a message that is one message from tcp 
example:
mess1 is : 0x40 0x50 0x55 etc
i call the parser (in a thread) and a fire a result event

Comment: You can write a parser which works as a state machine and can be pushed each piece of data as it is received. (This is what I do btw)  This is a lot harder than building the whole message first and then parsing the whole message at once.

Comment: when i received a tcp message i put the message in a BlockingQueue and call the parser(in the separate thread) then the parser take the message from a BlockingQueue and parse and fire the events?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117176/discussion-between---and-peter-lawrey).

Comment: You could do all that. TCP has a read queue of 64 KB by default (And I usually increase it to 1-4 MB) and I generally don't find you need to copy from the TCP queue to an in Java queue, but it can help in some cases. To start with, I would read from the TCP and pass the data directly to the parser in the same thread. I would only use a second thread if this didn't perform fast enough.